# Responsive canvas element?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I having issues to make a responsive canvas element. I using soundmanager2.js plugin with 360ui and its render a canvas element to show soundwave/spectrum– and i've to scenarios.

First. Using css below soundmanager.js render a HUGE canvas. Around width="3840"

```
.player-warp {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; }

.ui360 .sm2-canvas.hi-dpi {
position: absolute;
left: -50%;
top: -50%;}
```

Second. Using css below soundmanager.js render normally canvas. But not responsive.

```
.player-warp {
position: relative;
width: 225px;
height: 225px; }

.ui360 .sm2-canvas.hi-dpi {
position: absolute;
left: -50%;
top: -50%;}
```

How can resize/make it responsive?

Comment: use media queries, or show your full code, i will help with demo

Comment: A canvas element can't be "responsive" without scripting. At most you'll be able to get a stretched/squashed canvas.

Answer (score 0):

first: try can you please show what your goal is(what you want the page to look like)

If my perception of your goal is correct, you can use the following style code:

```css
        * {
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        html {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        body {
            width: 100vw;
            background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
        }
        div#mainContainer {
            margin: calc((100vh - ((6/7) * 100vw)) / 2) 0px;
            width: 100vw;
            height: calc((6/7) * 100vw);
            background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
            z-index: 1;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        @media only screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 7/6) {
            div#mainContainer {
                margin: 0px calc((100vw - ((7/6) * 100vh)) / 2);
                width: calc((7/6) * 100vh);
                height: 100vh;
            }
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

Just change iframe to canvas and edit accordingly